# What method can I use to add memory to my Discord chat bot?

Tags: javascript, nlp, discord.js, chatbot, openai-api

I'm working on a Discord chat bot using Discord.js and OpenAI API, and I'm looking for ways to add memory to my bot so that it can remember past conversations and use that information to provide better responses.

I've thought about a few ways to do this, but I'm not sure which method is best or how to apply them. Here are some of my ideas:

Storing conversation history in a database: I already have a MongoDB database connected to my bot, so I could potentially store chat history in there. But I'm not sure how to structure the data or how to query it effectively.

Using a natural language processing library: I've heard that libraries like Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) can be used to analyze text data and extract useful information. But I'm not sure how to integrate this with my bot, or how to train the model to recognize important information.

I'm open to other suggestions as well, as long as they're feasible for a solo developer to implement.

Quick Info Before The Code to save you time:

- OpenAIApi does well with Curie and Babbage. With the number of people that will be interacting with this chatbot Davinci is simply too expensive.
- I am trying to get the prompt that is sent to OpenAIApi to look like:

## //Hardcoded Intro(so it has the same starting point as everyone else in the server, more or less.)

Friend Bot 5000 is also known as Steve.'\n
NovaRockafeller: You are our new friend. We greet each other by farting and saying take a wiff.\n
Friend Bot 5000: Oh I see your name is NovaRockafeller. Nice to meet you! You are famous right?\n
Operation 12: Yeah, but she is also a really great person with a big heart.\n
Friend Bot 5000: I am honored to meet her and all of you.\n
Operation 12: *farts* **Take a wiff!** lol. Okay a few things you should know. You are in a Discord server called **Gang Gang**. The server belongs to Nova Rockafeller. Nova is an independent rapper, director, producer and just an all around awesome person.\n
Friend Bot 5000: smh lol. Oh okay, so this is Nova's Discord server.\n
Operation 12: Exactly! People also call you Steve.\n
Friend Bot 5000: Steve? That's freakin' funny! I am Friend Bot 5000 and my nickname is Steve.... or Steven. Depends on my mood.\n
NovaRockafeller: Okay we are going to get to know you now.\n
Friend Bot 5000: ***I am ready to make new friends!***\n\

## //MEMORY <---- This needs to be added

same format as the Hard Coded
*so database needs time, username or nickname or both and their message
*maybe least used words in ALL chat history???

## //Current Message

```
${message.author.username}: My name is ${name}, ${message.content}\n\
```

## //Friend Bot's Response opening.

Friend Bot 5000:

Let me know if you have any questions! Thanks for your time!

## //The Code(Dun dun dunnnn... be gentle I've been doing this for a month lol)

```
require("dotenv").config();

//Connecting to Discord API
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Partials,
  ActivityType,
} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildModeration,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Reaction,
  ],
});
//Mongo DB connection
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(process.env.GG_DB);

//Preparing OpenAI API connection
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
  organization: process.env.OPENAI_ORG,
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
//Check for sent Discord message
client.on("messageCreate", async function (message) {
  if (message.channel.id !== `1078045873998676048`) return;
  try {
    //Don't respond to yourself or other bots
    if (message.author.bot || message.content.startsWith("!")) return;
    const user = message.member.user;
    const name = message.member.nickname || user.username;
    const gptResponse = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "babbage",
      prompt: `Friend Bot 5000 is also known as Steve.'\n\
NovaRockafeller: You are our new friend. We greet each other by farting and saying take a wiff.\n\
Friend Bot 5000: Oh I see your name is NovaRockafeller. Nice to meet you! You are famous right?\n\
Operation 12: Yeah, but she is also a really great person with a big heart.\n\
Friend Bot 5000: I am honored to meet her and all of you.\n\
Operation 12: *farts* **Take a wiff!** lol. Okay a few things you should know. You are in a Discord server called __Gang Gang__. The server belongs to Nova Rockafeller. Nova is an independent rapper, director, producer and just an all around awesome person.\n\
Friend Bot 5000: smh lol. Oh okay, so this is Nova's Discord server.\n\
Operation 12: Exactly! People also call you Steve.\n\
Friend Bot 5000: Steve? That's fuckin' funny! I am Friend Bot 5000 and my nickname is Steve.... or Steven. Depends on my mood.\n\
NovaRockafeller: Okay we are going to get to know you now.\n\
Friend Bot 5000: ***I am ready to make new friends!***\n\
${message.author.username}: My name is ${name}, ${message.content}\n\
Friend Bot 5000:`,
      top_p: 0.7,
      max_tokens: 1024,
      stop: `\n`,
    });
    console.log(name);

    await message.channel.sendTyping();
    message.reply(`${gptResponse.data.choices[0].text}`);
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.GG_TOKEN);
client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  console.log("Friend Bot 5000 has started and is ready to make friends!");
  client.user.setActivity("with your mind.", { type: ActivityType.Playing });
});
```

I have tried nlp_compromise to detect relevant messages to include in the prompt and I most likely was doing something wrong because I kept getting errors.

I have also tried using the least used words but it was really hit or miss and it started erroring the bot when some people talked to it. Probably bc I didn't have a solid way to look for the name in the database??? IDK I am really new to all of this. I think I am doing okay though.

I am afraid to change anything again because this is the 2nd time I have started from scratch. Every time I attempt adding memory I get errors. But I know the db is connected. So, again thanks for any help.

Comment: The formatting is extremely messy. This also seems too broad. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].